# Selectively remove a warning message using GCC

Tags: gcc, warnings

This piece of code:

```
Int32 status;
printf("status: %x", status)
```

gives me the following warning:

```
jpegthread.c:157: warning: format '%x' expects type 'unsigned int', but argument 3 has type 'Int32'
```

I know I can get rid of it by casting the type, but is it possible with a GCC compiler flag to get rid of that particular type of warning, and still use [`-Wall`](http://-Wall)?

Comment: What you should probably actually do is include `<inttypes.h>` and then `printf("status : %" PRIx32, status)`, and also convert to unsigned integer first.

Comment: Also if you can, try to use the standard `intX_t` types from `<stdint.h>` if writing new code, anyone reading.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

If you need that code to work portable then you should cast the argument to *unsigned int*, as the int type may have a different size than Int32 on some platforms.

To answer your question about disabling specific warnings in GCC, you can enable specific warnings in GCC with *-Wxxxx* and disable them with *-Wno-xxxx*.

From the [GCC Warning Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> You can request many specific warnings with options beginning `-W`, for example `-Wimplicit` to request warnings on implicit declarations. Each of these specific warning options also has a negative form beginning `-Wno-` to turn off warnings; for example, `-Wno-implicit`. This manual lists only one of the two forms, whichever is not the default.

For your case the warning in question is *`-Wformat`*

> `-Wformat`

Check calls to printf and scanf, etc., to make sure that the arguments supplied have types appropriate to the format string specified, and that the conversions specified in the format string make sense. This includes standard functions, and others specified by format attributes (see *Function Attributes*), in the printf, scanf, strftime and strfmon (an [X/Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open) extension, not in the C standard) families (or other target-specific families). Which functions are checked without format attributes having been specified depends on the standard version selected, and such checks of functions without the attribute specified are disabled by `-ffreestanding` or `-fno-builtin`.

> The formats are checked against the format features supported by GNU libc version 2.2. These include all ISO C90 and C99 features, as well as features from the Single Unix Specification and some BSD and GNU extensions. Other library implementations may not support all these features; GCC does not support warning about features that go beyond a particular library's limitations. However, if `-pedantic` is used with `-Wformat`, warnings will be given about format features not in the selected standard version (but not for strfmon formats, since those are not in any version of the C standard). See Options Controlling C Dialect.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: how can one disable a specific warning normally included in -Wall without turning off -Wall? Or is that impossible?

Comment: @AaronCampbell: `-Wall -Wno-format` turns off the format warnings turned on by `-Wall`.

Comment: +1 for not lecturing about types etc and actually showing how to turn off certain warnings with -Wno-xxxx.

Answer (score 64):

It looks like the GCC manual does provide a way to do this with a #pragma, actually (contrary to what [Aiden Bell says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925179/selectively-remove-a-warning-message-using-gcc/925198#925198)):

*[6.62.13 Diagnostic Pragmas](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html)*

E.g., for the [-Wuninitialized](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wuninitialized) warning, you can do...

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wuninitialized"
```

... to suppress the warning, or...

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wuninitialized"
```

... to treat it as a warning (not an error) even if you're building with [-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Werror).

Comment: Probably at the time of writing it didnt. I am looking at the 4.1.2 manual, and it isn't supported in that.

Answer (score 12):

I used the following CFLAGS:

```
-Wall -Wformat=0
```

Comment: Never really had the requirement, but I can see it being handy :)

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What is the syntax? Is it used with configure or make? Like what do you mean?? Is there a semi colon between the command and make? It's good information, but it couldn't be anymore vague.

Comment: @Owl it can be complicated, with make `CFLAGS="-Wall -Wformat=0" make` works in most shell, make is very old and doesn't expect a shell so `make CFLAGS="-Wall -Wformat=0"` is also valid. with configure, either `CFLAGS="-Wall -Wformat=0" ./configure` or `./configure CFLAGS="-Wall -Wformat=0` should work. Configure might be picky about having them on the right hand side (assuming this is autotools's configure). configure "bakes in" the options, so after configure use make without CFLAGS anywhere, it will be ignored. check your build systems docs for how to pass c compiler flags.

Answer (score 5):

I presume you are looking for the

```
#ifdef WIN32
#pragma warning (disable: #num of the warning)
#endif
```

Equivalent in GCC...

You can search for options such as **-Wno-conversion -Wno-format-security** that do the job in *[3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html)*.

But in terms of the #pragma directive:

I *quote* from the **GCC mailing list from Google**:

> GCC does not, currently, provide the #pragma facility you are looking for.
>
> Do not lose hope!  There are viable
> alternatives.
>
> The first best way to fix the code so
> it no longer emits the warning. Alas,
> you've stated you cannot do this.  :-(
>
> NOTE:  Have warnings turned up as
> verbose as your team can tolerate!
> [see below]
>
> The next best way to ignore the
> undesired warning is to post-process
> the output of GCC to a script (such as
> a Perl script) that strips out the
> specific, exact warning you want to
> ignore.
>
> The next way to ignore the undesired
> warning is to disable the warning for
> that translation unit.
> -Wno-foozle-mcgoogle, just for that particular translation unit.  That's a
> mighty big hammer, though.  And if the
> warning is in a header file, it may be
> pervasive throughout your entire
> project -- to which I'd direct you to
> the post-processing script solution
> (assuming you are disallowed from
> fixing the code).

So currently no, there is no #pragma directive to disable specific warnings. Rather than using *-Wall* you could turn on as many warnings as you can minus specific ones.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_31.html

**Or fix the code**

Comment: Incorrect according to the GCC manual: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: It is funny how people developing my compiler knows better than me what warnings I need and not. But it turns into hilarity when people on online forums also know it.

Comment: or fix the code... except when the warning is caused by a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=61414) and there's no switch to disable it :(

Comment: The second link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.network-theory.co.uk."*