# Stop GCC out-of-range shift warning in unreachable code

Tags: c, gcc

Given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
  if (sizeof (long) > sizeof (int)) {
    long x = 42;
    x <<= CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int);
  }

  printf("sizeof (long) == %d\n", (int) sizeof (long));
  printf("sizeof (int) == %d\n", (int) sizeof (int));

  return 0;
}
```

On a platform where the sizes are equal I get this, with various version of GCC:

```
$ gcc -Wall shiftcomplain.c  -o shiftcomplain
shiftcomplain.c: In function ‘main’:
shiftcomplain.c:8:5: warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
$ ./shiftcomplain 
sizeof (long) == 4
sizeof (int) == 4
```

The code block is not reachable when the types have an equal size, so the bad shift will never execute. It will only execute if `long` is wider than `int`, in which case the shift will not be out of range for that type.

How can we eliminate this annoying warning, with these constraints:

- I don't want to disable it globally because it is useful (when not falsely positive).
- I don't want split the shift---that is, perform it as two consecutive left shifts which add to the desired shift size.
- I don't want to convert the `if` test into a preprocessor `#if`. (This is easy to do in this case with `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`, but troublesome in the actual program.)

---

Based on `n.m.`'s answer, I'm using something very similar to the following pattern:

```
const int condition = sizeof (long) > sizeof (int);

if (condition) {
  /*...*/
  x <<= CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int) * condition;
}
```

This pattern applied in my actual code suppresses the diagnostic, and the generated code doesn't change compared to not multiplying by `condition`.

Comment: This should go away if you use an optimization flag? e.g. `-O2`

Comment: @M.M What should go away?

Comment: @M.M. Certainly, the warning doesn't go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <<= (sizeof (long) > sizeof (int) ? CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int) : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same path as n.m. but came up with the following which seems more semantically what might have been intended (the top sizeof(int) bytes are from x).

```
x <<= (sizeof(long) - sizeof(int))*CHAR_BIT;
```

Comment: You are assuming `sizeof(long) - sizeof(int) == sizeof(int)` which is not necessarily true.

Comment: True, I noticed that. The question is whether the intent is to left-justify the field or what? n.m. did the exact transcription.

Comment: On some weird platform with 6 byte longs and 4 byte ints, do you want it to shift by 2 bytes or shift by four and get the warning and cut off the field?

Comment: BTW, both of these answers are somewhat unsatisfying. I also wish GCC had a localized way to silence warnings for "false positives" or "intentional" constructs once they have been checked. Oooh, I just found: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125889/5226168 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3394268/5226168. YAY!!!

Comment: @BlueMoon - oh, that was just rhetorical :) Maybe I should have said "did the author".