# Remove "ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field" warnings in C++/GNU

Tags: c++, gcc, suppress-warnings

We're working on a bigger embedded project, where we are using pre-compiled libraries. When compiling, lines where foreign code is used throw a huge amount of warnings. One occuring really often is

```
warning: ignoring packed attribute because of unpacked non-POD field '....'
```

This happens with gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q and Eclipse for embedded C/C++, version: 2020-09 (4.17.0).

I found multiple ways to get rid of warnings:

1. Add Comment `// @suppress ("warning ....")`, which does not work in that case.
2. As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925179/selectively-remove-warning-message-gcc), one can disable a specific warning using the warning number and *-Wno-xxxx.*
3. We could disable the whole group to which a warning belongs, see the first list [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html). I added `-Wpacked` to the makefile just to see what happens, it added 48'000 warnings. So this is probably not our candidate.

Does anybody know the warning number/category for that one? Or how do disable it in any other way?

Comment: `-W...` enables warnings, to disable try `-Wno-...`, eg `-Wno-packed`. But did you try analysing the code where the warning is triggered? I doubt the warning is triggered for nothing.

Comment: That's the point where it gets tricky. The foreign FW is a blackbox to us, we only see the headers. The message basically says "I did not leave away the padding because the non-POD field isn't packed and has padding", and results in a higher storage usage.
Using `-Wno-packed` didn't help, but it should.
I also stumbled upon [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58798) and thought it wouldn't apply to me because the bug is so old (2013). But apparently it's still not solved.

Comment: Just saw that we are mixing `#pragma pack` and `__attribute__((packed))`, which might lead to these warnings: [Bug 60972 - Mixing #pragma pack and __attribute__((packed)) leads to spurious warning](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60972)