# Disable type-limits check for a macro

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a simple `SIGNOF` macro:

```
#define SIGNOF(a) ((a) < 0 ? -1 : 1)
```

If `a` is negative it should return -1, otherwise 1. If `a` is an unsigned type, it should always return 1 and the compiler can optimize away the negative code path.

However, GCC rightfully warns me that

```
error: comparison of unsigned expression in ‘< 0’ is always false [-Werror=type-limits]
   29 | #define SIGNOF(a) ((a) < 0 ? -1 : 1)
```

But in this case I actually *want* this behavior. Is there any way to tell the compiler that this is intentional, similar to `/* fall-though */` in a switch-case?

Comment: Why not avoid using the macro when the type is unsigned?  When don't you know the type of your variable?

Comment: I want to use this macro inside of another macro: `#define DIV_ROUND(a, b) ((a) + SIGNOF(a) * (b)/2) / (b)`

Comment: You are missing a set of parentheses around the expression as a whole in your proposed macro.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler You could have a macro that expands to a signed or unsigned type. But that's a problematic practice!

Comment: Make two versions of the macro? Or you can use generic selection macro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/935667/421195  See also: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options

Comment: A negative result (but maybe it will inspire someone else): — I've tried playing with the `_Pragma` operator using `#define P0 _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push")  _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wtype-limits\"")` and
 `#define P1 _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")` without being able to embed those in a macro.  When I run `cpp source.c`, P0 expands to 6 lines with `#` controls and P1 expands into 3 lines, and I've not been able to embed them in another macro usefully.  Using `P0` on one line, then `SIGNOF` on the next, and `P1` on the third line suppresses the warning or error.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports it, you can use `_Generic`:

```
#define SIGNOF(a) _Generic(a, unsigned char: 1,          \
                              unsigned short: 1,         \
                              unsigned int: 1,           \
                              unsigned long: 1,          \
                              unsigned long long: 1,     \
                              default: (a) < 0 ? -1 : 1)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this falls back to `default` for `UINT32_MAX` where it then complains about `comparison of unsigned expression in ‘< 0’ is always false`

Comment: @user1273684 Are you sure? https://ideone.com/PtE1VW - this shows that the type of UINT32_MAX is detected properly.

Comment: Yes this still fails with `-Werror=type-limits` https://godbolt.org/z/oGYcjranx

Comment: This is weird. In https://godbolt.org/z/TWG45vser the warning clearly shows that `UINT32_MAX` is considered `unsigned int`...

Comment: Looks like it is performing the type limits check *before* actually picking the right generic option. Here - it will produce the warning for two different (unrelated) lines:  https://godbolt.org/z/1dv6T1333

Comment: That does *somewhat* make sense, since those are all expressions, even if they're not evaluated. (Not that I necessarily agree with the warning.)

Comment: Well, it is kind of making this answer incorrect (in a sense it does not answer the question...)

Comment: @EugeneSh.: The link https://godbolt.org/z/oGYcjranx has a syntax error (extra `)` for the `unsigned short` selector), but once corrected, shows the problem with **gcc**: it complains about the 2 expansions `unsigned short` and `default` that have the constant expression, neither of which is selected for the type of `UINT32_MAX`, ie: `unsigned int`. This looks like a bug or at least a shortcoming, that does not occur with **clang** even with all warnings enabled.

Answer (score 2):

What works is

```
static inline int __signof(long long a)
{
    return a < 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

#define SIGNOF(a) _Generic(a, unsigned char: 1,          \
                              unsigned short: 1,         \
                              unsigned int: 1,           \
                              unsigned long: 1,          \
                              unsigned long long: 1,     \
                              default: __signof(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fix the warning problem, at the expense of evaluating the operand twice:

```
#define SIGNOF(a) ((a) == 0 ? +1 : ((a) > 0) ? +1 : -1)
```

I observe that since the proposed `DIV_ROUND()` macro evaluates both its arguments twice, it also has problems if the arguments have side effects (increments, function calls, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Time for a hideous workaround:

```
#define SIGNOF_(a) ((a) < 0 ? -1 : 1)

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define SIGNOF(a)   ({ \
        typeof(a) _a = (a); \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wtype-limits\"") \
        int _r = SIGNOF_(_a); \
        _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop") \
        _r; })
#else
#define SIGNOF(a)   SIGNOF_(a)
#endif
```

It makes use of GNU C "statement expressions" (`({ statements; })`) and the `typeof` operator. The initialization `_a = (a);` is to catch any `-Wtype-limit` warnings in the macro parameter `a` before the warning is temporarily disabled by the pragmas.